# PHP MYSQL Access denied for user Error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the 'Content' value from a specific row ID in mySql, I echoed the result in PHP, But i got "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)".
I tryed to check my query in phpMyAdmin, and i got the exact result I expected for.

Here is my code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXX", "XXX") or die (mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("XXX", $con) or die (mysql_error());

function head($d) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT Content FROM list WHERE ID = '$d'") or die(mysql_error());
        $post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        echo $post["Content"];
}


<h1> <?php head(1); ?> </h1>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: the configuration details are errate is simple

Answer (score 3):

The error message you quote sounds like the database isn't connected yet when you're making the call. If no connection exists, `mysql_query()` will try to establish a connection with default values (which usually are empty).

You should check your program flow and make sure you are actually connected to the database before making any queries.

Comment: +1 for this...Strongly agree..initially I took the error message wrong..thanks..gonna delete my answer

Comment: Man, write also which mysql is deprecated

Comment: Thank you, but, how can I check if I connected?

Comment: @Sam I've stopped doing that, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143382/138112 for reasons

Comment: @Noam you likely have an architectural problem. Are you sure you are actually calling `mysql_connect()` before trying to do a query?

Answer (score 0):

issue is with

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "ncode_hana", "NOAM7778")
```

chech that sqn user and pass are correct and this user has right over your selected db...

also, never share your orignial user ID  and password with anyone..

also, as Pekka told you need something like this

```
<h1> <?php include('yourdatabaseconnectionfile.php'); ?> <?php head(1); ?> </h1>
```

**ALTERNATIVELY**

```
 <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXX", "XXX") or die (mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db("XXX", $con) or die (mysql_error());

    <h1> <?php head(1); ?> </h1>


    function head($d) {

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT Content FROM list WHERE ID = '$d'") or die(mysql_error());
            $post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            echo $post["Content"];
    }
```

**ONE MORE OPTION**
add connection string in function (not recommended though)

```
     function head($d) {
mysql_connect("localhost", "ncode_hana", "NOAM7778"); 
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT Content FROM list WHERE ID = '$d'") or die(mysql_error());
                $post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                echo $post["Content"];
        }
```

Comment: This is not the issue (Look at the error message)

Comment: I actualy did it already... Thats not the whole code

Answer (score 0):

move your first two lines to your function:

```
function head($d) {
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXX", "XXX") or die (mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("XXX", $con) or die (mysql_error());

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT Content FROM list WHERE ID = '$d'") or die(mysql_error());
        $post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        echo $post["Content"];
}


<h1> <?php head(1); ?> </h1>
```